# Change the height of a Richtext field rendered with <apex:inputField>

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

I am using `<apex:inputField>` to display a richtext field on my VF page as I found out that the "Upload Images" functionality only exits when I render those fields not with `<apex:inputTextarea richtext="true"... />`.

My problem now is that there is no `rows` attribute on `<apex:inputField>` to set the height of the textarea. I tried just adding a `style="height:xyz px"`  but this didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how fine grain of a control you need on the height you can just set the # Visible Lines property of the actual field on the Custom Field Definition.  It must be between 10 and 50 lines, though.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** FWIW, in my org the "Upload Images" functionality works alright on Rich Text Area fields - maybe triple check your config? If you can resolve that, [@PeterKnolle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/change-the-height-of-a-richtext-field-rendered-with-apexinputfield/8086#8086) has the better answer.

Salesforce use [CKEditor](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.event.html) to decorate the richtext editor on top of a textarea. They leave the `editor` identifier in the global scope, and you can call `resize` to tweak as needed.

The nice way to do this would be to use the instanceReady hook:

```
<script>
  editor.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
    event.editor.resize(0, 400); //leave first parameter as 0 to affect only height.
  });
</script>
```

The nasty way to do this is to trash the CSS:

```
<style>
  .cke_contents {
    height: 400px !important;
  }
</style>
```

[image: upload images]

Comment: How did you embedd the textarea into your page? Its working with inputField but not with inputTextarea.

Comment: On a custom page: `<apex:page><apex:form><apex:inputTextarea richText="true" /></apex:form><script>editor.on('instanceReady', function() {editor.resize(0, 400);});</script></apex:page>` - note the script is _after_ the form.