# Pasting an image into the template of an outbound email

Tags: visualforce, email-template

We are currently using the standard frame-based email templates which are supplied by SF. In one of our applications we occasionally need to manually create an email to send out to clients regarding a particular case. However, we would like to be able to paste an image at the bottom of the template before it goes out. It's not an image which we can include in the template because it will be different every time (it's a graphic rendering of a specific solution). We can do this in the Free Form template by just clicking inside the frame at the bottom and pasting, but we can't do that in the Newsletter template which has multiple columns because it will mess up the formatting.

Ideally, we would be able to just have one more frame at the bottom of the Newsletter template which went all the way across the width of the template.

Anybody have any thoughts on this ? I am almost starting to think that I will have to re-create the entire template in manually created HTML within a VF page - but there's gotta be an easier way than that !

Sorry for the long explanation.

Thanks so much for any input you can give here.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm adding to this, but I have decided to try to take the email template which was built with the "HTML (using Letterhead)" method and recreate as a Visualforce page. I'm hoping I can somehow create a page which will allow the user to paste an image at the bottom of the page before sending out the email. I would like to take the html markup from that template and put it into the VF page I am creating.

Does anybody know a quick way of getting that markup code from the template? Is this all just a futile effort? Am I ultimately trying to do something that I won't be able to do in VF ?

Comment: I have been researching this further and have found this discussion : 

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/change-the-height-of-a-richtext-field-rendered-with-apexinputfield

I didn't want to de-rail that conversation by asking my own question. They say we can expand the rich text out to 400px. I want to put a rich text in a VF email template. Is there a way to expand it out further to allow it to hold images the size of a screenshot ? If not, is there a better way to do this in an email template ? Thank you very much for any help you can give me. This has been driving me mad!

Answer (score 1):

If you can put a `</tr>` (or `</td>`) followed by a `<colspan = #_of_columns>` and a `<tr>` tag (or `<td>` as appropriate) at the bottom of the body of your newsletter template, you'd have what you want provided the template is in html and wasn't created using APEX Table formatting.

If the template is done with APEX mark-up, you'd need to alter the template to add a table with 1 column and 1 row at the bottom of it so you could past your images into it.

As for getting the mark-up code, open the visualforce page in developer mode with Show View State in Development Mode enable in your personal profile. Both require you to go into SetUp, click on "My Personal Information", then "Personal Information" and enable the checkboxes for them. Once the visualforce page is loaded you'll be able to see it's source code (and edit it) by clicking on the icons at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the edit eyescream. Looks like I forgot to put the code inside of `code` markers. (blush)